# Gulp - errors, mess with npm

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, gulp

I work in project with laravel framework and I really can't deal with npm,
1) first the version of node was wrong so I upgrade with npm [like that](https://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs)
2) second I run `sudo npm install` and I have errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Unsupported
/home/student/PhpstormProjects/laravel
├─┬ gulp@3.9.0 
│ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ └── semver@4.3.6 
├─┬ gulp-util@3.0.7
│ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │   ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ └─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│   └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
├─┬ laravel-elixir@4.2.0
│ ├─┬ babel-preset-es2015@6.3.13
│ │ └─┬ babel-plugin-transform-regenerator@6.3.26
│ │   └─┬ babel-core@6.4.0
│ │     └─┬ babel-generator@6.4.2
│ │       └─┬ detect-indent@3.0.1
│ │         └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ ├─┬ babelify@7.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ babel-core@6.4.0
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-generator@6.4.2
│ │ │   └─┬ detect-indent@3.0.1
│ │ │     └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ browser-sync@2.11.0
│ │ ├─┬ chokidar@1.4.1
│ │ │ └─┬ readdirp@2.0.0
│ │ │   └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ ├─┬ eazy-logger@2.1.2
│ │ │ └─┬ opt-merger@1.1.1
│ │ │   └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ ├─┬ fs-extra@0.26.4
│ │ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ ├─┬ meow@3.3.0
│ │ │ └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ └─┬ opn@3.0.3
│ │   └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ browserify@11.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.4.10
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ ├─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ ├── glob@4.5.3 
│ │ ├─┬ labeled-stream-splicer@1.0.2
│ │ │ └─┬ stream-splicer@1.3.2
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ ├─┬ module-deps@3.9.1
│ │ │ ├── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └─┬ stream-combiner2@1.0.2
│ │ │   └─┬ through2@0.5.1
│ │ │     └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ ├─┬ read-only-stream@1.1.1
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ ├─┬ subarg@1.0.0
│ │ │ └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ └─┬ through2@1.1.1
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ ├── glob@5.0.15 
│ ├─┬ gulp-autoprefixer@2.3.1
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ gulp-babel@6.1.1
│ │ ├─┬ babel-core@6.4.0
│ │ │ └─┬ babel-generator@6.4.2
│ │ │   └─┬ detect-indent@3.0.1
│ │ │     └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ gulp-coffee@2.3.1
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ gulp-concat@2.6.0
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ gulp-cssnano@2.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ cssnano@3.4.0
│ │ │ └─┬ postcss-svgo@2.1.1
│ │ │   └─┬ svgo@0.6.1
│ │ │     └── mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ gulp-if@1.2.5
│ │ ├─┬ ternary-stream@1.2.3
│ │ │ └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ gulp-less@3.0.5
│ │ ├─┬ accord@0.20.5
│ │ │ └── semver@4.3.6 
│ │ ├─┬ less@2.5.3
│ │ │ └── mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ gulp-notify@2.2.0
│ │ ├─┬ node-notifier@4.4.0
│ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ └── semver@4.3.6 
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ gulp-phpspec@0.5.3
│ │ ├─┬ gulp-jshint@1.12.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ gulp-util@3.0.7
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │ │ │   └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ │     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ ├─┬ gulp-logger@0.0.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ gulp-util@3.0.7
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │ │ │   └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ │     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.5.1
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ ├─┬ gulp-todo@2.6.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ gulp-util@3.0.7
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │ │ │   └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ │     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ ├─┬ gulp-util@2.2.20
│ │ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │   ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ ├─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.5.1
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ └─┬ jshint@2.8.0
│ │   └─┬ htmlparser2@3.8.3
│ │     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ ├─┬ gulp-phpunit@0.11.3
│ │ ├─┬ gulp-messenger@0.7.0
│ │ │ ├─┬ gulp-debug@2.1.2
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ gulp-util@3.0.7
│ │ │ │ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ │ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ │ │     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ │ └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ ├─┬ gulp-util@2.2.20
│ │ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │   ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ ├─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └─┬ through2@0.5.1
│ │ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ └─┬ node-notifier@4.3.1
│ │   ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │   └── semver@4.3.6 
│ ├─┬ gulp-rev@5.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ └─┬ vinyl-file@1.3.0
│ │   └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ ├─┬ gulp-sass@2.1.1
│ │ ├─┬ node-sass@3.4.2
│ │ │ ├─┬ gaze@0.5.2
│ │ │ │ └─┬ globule@0.1.0
│ │ │ │   ├─┬ glob@3.1.21 
│ │ │ │   │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3 
│ │ │ │   │ └── inherits@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │   ├── lodash@1.0.2 
│ │ │ │   └── minimatch@0.2.14 
│ │ │ ├─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │ │ │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │ │ │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │ │   └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │ │     └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ │ ├── mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ │ ├─┬ node-gyp@3.2.1
│ │ │ │ ├─┬ fstream@1.0.8
│ │ │ │ │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ │ │ └── mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ │ │ ├── glob@4.5.3 
│ │ │ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │ └─┬ npmconf@2.1.2
│ │ │   └── semver@4.3.6 
│ │ └── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ ├─┬ gulp-sourcemaps@1.6.0
│ │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ ├─┬ gulp-uglify@1.5.1
│ │ └─┬ fancy-log@1.1.0
│ │   └─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │     └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │       ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │       ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │       ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │       │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │       │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │       │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │       │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │       │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │       └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │         └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │           └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ ├─┬ gulp-util@3.0.7
│ │ ├─┬ dateformat@1.0.12
│ │ │ └─┬ meow@3.7.0
│ │ │   ├── object-assign@4.0.1 
│ │ │   ├─┬ read-pkg-up@1.0.1
│ │ │   │ └─┬ read-pkg@1.1.0
│ │ │   │   ├─┬ load-json-file@1.1.0
│ │ │   │   │ └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │   │   └─┬ path-type@1.1.0
│ │ │   │     └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ │   └─┬ redent@1.0.0
│ │ │     └─┬ indent-string@2.1.0
│ │ │       └── repeating@2.0.0 
│ │ ├── minimist@1.2.0 
│ │ └─┬ multipipe@0.1.2
│ │   └─┬ duplexer2@0.0.2 
│ │     └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ ├─┬ gulp-watch@4.3.5
│ │ ├─┬ chokidar@1.4.2
│ │ │ └─┬ readdirp@2.0.0
│ │ │   └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ └─┬ vinyl-file@1.3.0
│ │   └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ ├─┬ merge-stream@0.1.8
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ vinyl-buffer@1.0.0
│ │ ├─┬ bl@0.9.4
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ vinyl-paths@1.0.0
│ │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ ├─┬ vinyl-source-stream@1.1.0
│ │ ├─┬ through2@0.6.5 
│ │ │ └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
│ │ └─┬ vinyl@0.4.6 
│ │   └── clone@0.2.0 
│ └─┬ watchify@3.7.0
│   ├─┬ browserify@13.0.0
│   │ └─┬ subarg@1.0.0
│   │   └── minimist@1.2.0 
│   └─┬ chokidar@1.4.2
│     └─┬ readdirp@2.0.0
│       └── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
├─┬ liftoff@2.2.0
│ ├── extend@2.0.1 
│ └─┬ findup-sync@0.3.0
│   └── glob@5.0.15 
└─┬ vinyl-fs@0.3.14
  ├─┬ glob-stream@3.1.18
  │ ├── glob@4.5.3 
  │ └─┬ through2@0.6.5 
  │   └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
  ├─┬ glob-watcher@0.0.6
  │ └─┬ gaze@0.5.2
  │   └─┬ globule@0.1.0
  │     ├─┬ glob@3.1.21 
  │     │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3 
  │     │ └── inherits@1.0.2 
  │     ├── lodash@1.0.2 
  │     └── minimatch@0.2.14 
  ├── mkdirp@0.5.1 
  ├── strip-bom@1.0.0 
  ├─┬ through2@0.6.5 
  │ └── readable-stream@1.0.33 
  └─┬ vinyl@0.4.6 
    └── clone@0.2.0
```

Could you help me? Meybe I should just rollback all things but I really don't know how. Any suggestion will be important for me.

**EDIT:**
When I try to run gulp:

```
 module.js:328
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './lib/UI'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:326:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:277:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/student/PhpstormProjects/laravel/node_modules/laravel-elixir/node_modules/browser-sync/node_modules/browser-sync-ui/index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

Comment: Tell us your npm version and show us your Gulpfile. I can only assume some of your packages need `lorash` in version lower than 2.0 which is not maintained and Gulp cannot install this.

Comment: npm version : 3.3.12

Comment: This may be unrelated to your problem, but your permissions are messed up if you have to run `sudo` with `npm install`. See: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions